# Пишу плагин для unturned, получаю ошибку в конcоли при попытке обработки команды

Tags: c#, unity3d

В коде делаю проверку, смотрит ли игрок на баррикаду, в удачном исходе должны пройти некоторые манипуляции с данным объектом.

```
if (PhysicsUtility.raycast(new Ray(look.aim.position, look.aim.forward), out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, RayMasks.BARRICADE_INTERACT))
        {
            InteractableDoorHinge hinge = hit.transform.GetComponent<InteractableDoorHinge>();

            if (hinge != null)
            {
                InteractableDoor door = hinge.door;
                bool open = !door.isOpen;

                Util.ToggleDoor(door, open);

                UnturnedChat.Say(caller, Util.Translate("door_toggle", open ? "opened" : "closed"));

                if (open && BreakAndEnter.instance.Configuration.Instance.AutoCloseDoors)
                    BreakAndEnter.instance.AutoCloseDoor(door);
            }
            else
                UnturnedChat.Say(caller, Util.Translate("invalid_door"));
        }
        else
            UnturnedChat.Say(caller, Util.Translate("no_object"));
```

Но при вызове команды получаю ошибку:

```
An error occured while executing storage []: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Кажется, что ошибка связана с `RayMasks.BARRICADE_INTERACT`, но понять, как инициализировать объект, не могу.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!